# Retrieve data from JSON based on ID

Tags: json, swift

I have some JSON as follows

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "locid": "352260",
    "name": "Clifton-on-Teme",
    "postcode": "WR6 6EW",
    "club": "Warley Wasps",
    "lat": "52.257011",
    "lon": "-2.443215",
    "type": "Soil"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "locid": "310141",
    "name": "Drayton Manor",
    "postcode": "ST18 9AB",
    "club": "Warley Wasps",
    "lat": "52.745810",
    "lon": "-2.102677",
    "type": "Soil"
  },
```

(This is an extract of 2 of the sets.)

and I have a code lookup as follows

```
func downloadtrackDetails(completed: @escaping DownLoadComplete) {
        Alamofire.request(trackURL).responseJSON { (response) in
            if let dict = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                if let postcode = dict[0]["postcode"] as? String {
                    self._postcode = postcode
                }
                if let trackType = dict[0]["type"] as? String {
                    self._trackType = trackType
                }
            }
            completed()
        }
    }
```

I have a number of items on my home screen each with an id assigned 1 to 8.  currently i can only return the first entry in the json dictionary when I run.  what do i need to do to get it to pull the data for a specific id.So if I click on the first icon which has an ID of one, it returns the postcode of WR6 6EW

Comment: What is the specific problem you're experiencing?

Comment: whichever icon I press on the home screen I get the same result, which is the data from the first set, i need it to only provide data from the set which matches the id

Comment: Did you expect to access any other object than the first when you hardcode the index to 0? What did you think `dict[0]` would do?

Comment: ha! I just figured it out as you replied, I have replaced the 0 with my var for id

Answer (score 1):

If the `id` key is not linked to the position in the array, you could simply iterate through your `dict` and only assign the `_postcode` property if the `id` property matches your ID:

```
for (key, item):[String, String] in dict {
    if item["id"] == "YOUR ID" {
        if let postcode = item["postcode"] as? String { /* ... */ }
        /* ... */
        break
    }
}
```

Or you could filter `dict` to only keep items whose ID is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your `dict` is an array and contains `[String:String]` dictionaries. That gets rid of some type casting.

You could use the `filter` function to get the item by `id`

```
     let id = "2"         

     if let array = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String, String>],
        let foundItem = array.filter({ $0["id"]! == id }).first {
            if let postcode = foundItem["postcode"] {
                self._postcode = postcode
            }
            if let trackType = foundItem["type"] {
                self._trackType = trackType
            }
        }
```